# PUN2 PhotonAvatarView doesn't detect Oculus standard teleport event

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, oculus, photon, oculusquest

My multiplayer VR project is based on **Unity3D**, **Oculus Integration v1.39** and **PUN2** running on Oculus Quest. I'm using the standard teleport script provided in the Oculus library. `PhotonAvatarView` is what I use to keep avatar position/rotation in sync across clients. 
Unfortunately, when a player teleports to a new location, the other one doesn't detect any change in the remote avatar. It seems like `PhotonAvatarView` doesn't see the change in location of the user, which is really strange. How can I fix it?

PhotonAvatarView code is available at this URL: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/demos-and-tutorials/oculusavatarsdk

Comment: Does it work in general? I mean what happens instead? The other player stays at the position but moves relative to it? Does Oculus move the correct object or do you maybe jave the `PhotonViewTransform` attached to a child/parent object which is not the one moved?

Comment: Technically it works well, meaning that the two players (A and B) can see each other moving when they walk in the room. But when A performs a teleport, then B simply doesn't detect the sudden change in location and sees as A is keep on moving in the same location. So basically their reference system goes off-sync and the player positions are not aligned to the room anymore. It doesn't make sense to me as the position of A changes and PhotonTransformView should send the change over the network.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification! Though, is it possible that the teleport is done on a parent GameObject moving the entire character without being synced on the network? Maybe photon only "knows" about the child moved relative to that parent?

Comment: It's possible, also I'm using the ExitGames PUN2 PhotonAvatarView which relies upon the Oculus Avatar API for synchronising the position instead of a classic PhotonTransformView which has an advanced configuration for detecting teleport. This gave me an idea: I will write a component which will detect sudden changes in the avatar position between two consecutive frames and will sync that over the network. If it works I will publish it, but of course, if somebody knows a better (and possibly simpler) solution it would be great.

Comment: @derHugo I can confim your theory was correct, teleport was updating the parent game object so I had to use a separate PhotonView+PhotonTransformView in it to sync the position update. I would convert your comment into an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.